# Sum weighted Rayleigh distribution

Tags: r, distribution, weighted

I simulated data with `nrow=1000` (individuals) and `ncol=100` (days) for step lengths according to a Pareto distribution function:

```r
set.seed(10)
sim_data <- replicate(100, VGAM::rpareto(1000, shape=7, scale=500))
sim_data <- as.data.frame(sim_data)
set.seed(10)
sim_data[,1:50] <- sim_data[50]*(-1) ##assign directionality
sim_data_directions <- as.data.frame(sim_data)
##randomize columns
sim_data <- sim_data_directions[,sample(ncol(sim_data_directions))] 
x <- c(1:31) ## for variable 'days' to associate to each step length
set.seed(10)
df_sim <- cbind(sim_data, t(apply(sim_data,1, function(x) {
  i1 <- sample(seq_along(x), 1)
  out <- sum(sample(x, i1))
  c(days = i1, step_lengths = out)}
))) ## create step lengths
##adding weights for each level in variable days
df_sim <- as.data.frame(dplyr::add_count(df_sim, days))
```

using this dataset `df_sim`, with simulated values for step lengths, the time associated to each step length in days, and the weight (number of values for each time variable in days, I want to sum up the distributions, using a Rayleigh distribution function, where the distribution for each level of days is weighted, something like this:

```
rayleigh_distr <- sum(n*function (x) x*exp(-1*(x/2*sigma)^2)/sigma^2)
```

where `n` is the weights.
How do I sum up the distributions for each day according to their weights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it looks like you have an error in your Rayleigh PDF. It should be:

```
x*exp(-(x/sigma)^2/2)/sigma^2
```

It looks like you want `rayleigh_distr` as a function returning the PDF of a Rayleigh [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) with weights `n` and scale parameters `sigma`. If that's the case, it would be (for a scalar `x`):

```
rayleigh_distr <- function(x, sigma, n) sum(n*x*exp(-(x/sigma)^2/2)/sigma^2)
```

where `sigma` and `n` are vectors of equal length.

If you want to pass a vector for `x` (not necessarily the same length as `sigma` and `n`), then this should work:

```
library(Rfast)
rayleigh_distr <- function(x, sigma, n) colsums(n*eachrow(exp(-(outer(1/sigma, x))^2/2), x)/sigma^2)
```

It will return a vector the same length as `x`.

**Update:**

The CDF would be:

```
rayleigh_cdf <- function(x, sigma, n) colSums(n*(1 - exp(-(outer(1/sigma, x))^2/2)))
```

Comment: @N.J. I just updated the first two code snippets--I had left off the `/sigma^2`.

Comment: hi @jblood94. could you please help me write the weighted rayleigh CDF?

Comment: @N.J. I updated my answer to include a function for the CDF.